# Number of real values of $t$ in a circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> The number of real values of $t\in\mathbb{R}$  for which exactly one circle passing through the points $(2,-3)$ and $(t,2t-1)$ and touching the line $16x-2y+27=0$ is

Here the point $(t,2t-1)$ always lie in line $y=2x-1\implies 2x-y-1=0$

Now let $(h,k)$ be the center of circle, Then using distance formula

$\displaystyle \sqrt{(h-2)^2+(k+3)^2}=\frac{|16h-2k+26|}{\sqrt{16^2+2^2}}=\frac{|2h-k-1|}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}}\cdots (1)$

From $\displaystyle 16h-2k+26=52(2h-k-1)$

$88h-50k-78=0\implies 44h-25k-39=0$

Now equating $k$ from above equation in $(1)$ St equation

But this is very lengthy way.

Please have a look, how can I go ahead?

Comment: Are you not using $k$ for two different numbers when you say the center of the circle is at $(h,k)$ and the point $(k,2k-1)$ is on the circle?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang I have edited it.

Comment: I fatally misread the question, thanks for commenting.

Comment: Also, I take it “touching” implies tangency while “passing through” indicates transversality?

Comment: "Exactly one" leads me to believe that the circle need to touch both lines and go thru a point. This happens for exactly two values of $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the point on line $=2−1$, and $B=(2,-3)$. Let $F$ be the point where line $AB$ meets line $r$ of equation $16−2+27=0$. If $A$ and $B$ are on the same side of $r$, then a circle $ABT$ exists, tangent to $r$ at $T$. And if $T'$ is the reflection of $T$ about $F$, then circle $ABT'$ is also tangent to $r$, due to the properties of radical axis $AB$.

Hence, if $A$ and $B$ are on the same side of $r$, we always get two tangent circles, whatever the position of $A$, unless $AB$ is parallel to $r$. And that only happens for $t=3$.

If $A$ lies on $r$ ($t=-29/12$), then $A=F=T=$ intersection point of the lines and we also have a single circle, tangent to $r$ at $A$. Finally, if $A$ and $B$ are on opposite sides of $r$, no tangent circle exists.

In summary, there are only $2$ real values of $t$ for which exactly one circle through $A$, $B$ and touching $r$ exists.

[image]